# Log4j-2 custom log level code generator

Tags: log4j2

I would like `Logger` to have my custom logging level method implemented. For example i would like to call `log.custom("custom level log")`. According to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html#CodeGen) it is possible but there is not enough hints for me. Can someone help me with understanding what does this command exactly do?

```
java -cp log4j-core-2.8.jar \  
     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.tools.Generate$ExtendedLogger \
     com.mycomp.ExtLogger DIAG=350 NOTICE=450 VERBOSE=550 > com/mycomp/ExtLogger.java
```

What steps should I take after this command exits successfully? What exactly should I swap and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the tool does is generate source code that you can include in your project. The intention is that you use the generated class instead of the standard Log4j2 Logger.

Before running the tool, you need to decide what to call your custom levels and where they rank, relative to the existing levels. The manual page shows a table with the int values of the built-in levels. The int value of your custom level will probably be in between these values.

In the quoted example, the tool will generate a class named `ExtLogger` in the `com.mycomp` package that extends the standard Log4j2 Logger with three custom levels (DIAG, NOTICE and VERBOSE). DIAG's int value is 350 so it sits between WARN (300) and INFO (400).

The tool writes the generated source code to the console. The example shows how you can redirect that output to a file. You can then include this file in your project.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Can you please check this error?   https://gist.github.com/sdwsk/47b86d243023b1583d340889a89639f6

Comment: I noticed something strange: The error message says that the `Generate` class doesn't have a main method, but what you're trying to execute is the `Generate$ExtendedLogger` inner class. The inner class _does_ have a main method. Perhaps the command line is interpreting the `$Extended` as an environment variable. Can you try quoting the fully qualified class name?

Comment: I had to replace "ord.apache..." with 'ord.apache...'